# How to populate a list inside my viewmodel from database?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I just started learning C#, and my question may sound stupid...

How can I populate a list inside my viewmodel using data from my db?

My Viewmodels:

```
  public class TransferSpecificClientsViewModel
{

    public string TransferFrom { get; set; }
    public string TransferTo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientsToTransfer> ClientsToTransferList { get; set; }

}

public class ClientsToTransfer
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

And in the controller probably I need something like:

```
var  model = (from p in db.Clients
                 select new TransferSpecificClientsViewModel()
                 {
                     // And here I need to populate the ClientsToTransferList with data from db.Clients... I think it should probably be something like
                     //ClientsToTransferList.ClientId  = p.Id
                     //ClientsToTransferList.UserId = p.UserId
                     //ClientsToTransferList.Name = p.Name });
```

But for each client in my database

I just dont know how to make it work... And being new to C# I dont know how to properly search about what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. I'd change `virtual ICollection<ClientsToTransfer>` to simply `List<ClientsToTransfer>` and do the select just like you're thinking.

```
//...initialize TransferFrom and TransferTo properties of your view model
model.ClientsToTransferList = 
             (from p in db.Clients
             select new ClientsToTransfer()
             {
                 ClientId  = p.Id
                 UserId = p.UserId
                 Name = p.Name 
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me... I'm still having problems with this... I did as you said and now i get "Cannot initialize  type TransferSpecificClientsViewModel because it does not implement "System Collection Ienumerable"  invalid Initializer member declarator"

Comment: Sorry about that, I was selecting the wrong class. Fixed.

Make sure your `model` variable is the same type as your view model.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! (Also I had to remove ClientsToTransferList. from the part inside the select [eg in  ClientsToTransferList.ClientId] )

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.